# Sum of count from external table

Tags: sql, count, sum

I need to search for the sum of the games made by specific developers. I have two tables:

```
 _____________________________
|____________GAMES____________|
| Id | Title | id_dev |  hits |
| 01 | abc   |    1   |   20  |
| 02 | xyz   |    2   |   15  |
| 03 | cde   |    1   |   9   |

 _______________
|__DEVELOPERS___|
| Id |    Title |
| 01 |    poi   |
| 02 |    asd   |
| 03 |    qwe   |
```

I want result formatted like `Developers title 40`, where 40 is the sum of all hits of the games with the ID of this developer.  How can I go about this?

```
SELECT developers.title, COUNT(count) AS total FROM (SELECT COUNT(games.hits) AS count
FROM games
GROUP BY id_dev
HAVING count > 1) as A
FROM developers
JOIN games
WHERE developers.id = games.id_dev
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple join and aggregate, so you are overcomplicating things:

```
select d.id, d.title, sum(g.hits)
from games g join
     developers d
     on g.id_dev = d.id
group by d.id, d.title;
```